# In NextJS we get the error "React Component as default export in" but it's for a file i want in the directory

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js, reselect

I'm using reselect and redux with nextjs, and would like to keep the reducers, actions, and selectors with the component file for organization reasons. Unfortunately it gives an "Build optimization failed: found pages without a React Component as default export in", is there any way to ignore a "redux" folder or similar?

Comment: Can you post the relevant files here?

Comment: Every js file in pages directory [has to be a page](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8617#issuecomment-527779921). That means if you're js file is not a page then don't put it there.

Answer (score 1):

If your redux folder, and any other redux files, are not in the pages directory it should be ignored.